# Is there documentation on Qt Platform Plugin Arguments?

Tags: qt

I am trying to find out what kind of arguments I can pass to platform plugins via qt.conf or by some other means, but the only documentation I can find is this:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

Is this all Qt provides documentation wise for platform plugins?

Specifically I am looking for rendering options for both text, simple objects, and pixmap data.

Comment: You'll have to look at the source code. It's not documented, I'm afraid.

Comment: @KubaOber Do you happen to know what files specifically for Windows and Linux? I was thinking the qtbase/platforms is what I'm looking for, but not absolutely certain.

Answer (score 2):

No document but sources:

```
src\qtbase\src\plugins\platforms\cocoa\qcocoaintegration.mm
src\qtbase\src\plugins\platforms\windows\qwindowsintegration.cpp
etc.
```

They have parseOptions method:

```
    foreach (const QString &param, paramList) {
    if (param.startsWith(QLatin1String("fontengine="))) {
        if (param.endsWith(QLatin1String("freetype"))) {
            options |= QWindowsIntegration::FontDatabaseFreeType;
        } else if (param.endsWith(QLatin1String("native"))) {
            options |= QWindowsIntegration::FontDatabaseNative;
        }
    } else if (param.startsWith(QLatin1String("dialogs="))) {
        if (param.endsWith(QLatin1String("xp"))) {
            options |= QWindowsIntegration::XpNativeDialogs;
        } else if (param.endsWith(QLatin1String("none"))) {
            options |= QWindowsIntegration::NoNativeDialogs;
        }
    } else if (param == QLatin1String("gl=gdi")) {
        options |= QWindowsIntegration::DisableArb;
    } else if (param == QLatin1String("nodirectwrite")) {
        options |= QWindowsIntegration::DontUseDirectWriteFonts;
    ...
```